# Pie Chart error public static double

Tags: c#, jquery, json, webservice, asp

Tengo 4 gráficas pastel en ASP.NET C# , utilizo webservice y Jquery, algo no está funcionando apropiadamente. El principal error es el siguiente:

Tengo un sliderbar que si no lo deslizo en los primeros 10 minutos la memoria de la información que se guardó en variables matriciales de tipo STATIC desaparecen o generan algún conflicto. Por otro lado si el trackbar lo deslizo inicialmente antes de los 10 min todo trabaja bien. Deslizo el trackbar para modificar la gráfica pastel en la webpage a través de webmethods.

Ahora, explico a detalle:

Cuando la webpage carga muestra un modal de bootstrap para solicitar el filtro de fecha. Escojo el año y el mes. Para éste ejemplo tomaremos julio 2016, se ejecuta el evento y consulta al servidor valores de Enero 2016 - Julio 2016. En éste evento lleno las variables estáticas de tipo matriz bidimensional, cada variable contendrá el mes y el valor "Q" decimal que arrojó la consulta del respectivo mes.

Con el código de abajo inicialmente lo que hago es consultar inicialmente al servidor de Enero a Julio 2016 a través de SQL commands y luego agregar por un ciclo FOR los datos de todos los meses a las variables C1, C1_, D1, D1_, E1, E1_, la última sección donde se llena KBInfo1_III_B  es para arrojar un JSON y estas variables "RUTA, MONT, a3, CANT" son las que el pastel ocupara para llenarse a través de un jquery. Ahora que las variables matriciales están full, si yo deslizo el trackbar entonces a través de webmoth llama éstas variables y actualiza las del JSON.

```
//VARIABLES PARA LOS CALLBACKS.
public static decimal[,] C1, C1_, D1, D1_, E1, E1_; 

public class KBInfo1_III_B
{
    public string ruta { get; set; }
    public decimal? a3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cant { get; set; }

}

    public IEnumerable GetER1_B(int ano_, List<int> ddl_mes_int)
    {
        List<KBInfo1_III_B> kbItems = new List<KBInfo1_III_B>();
        string month_s = string.Empty;

        int v = ddl_mes_int.Count;
        Ruta = new decimal[16]; //Num de rutas
        Ruta_ = new decimal[16]; //Monto de rutas
        Name = new string[16]; //Nombre de rutas
        RutaP = new decimal[16]; // Porcentaje de ruta 

        C1 = new decimal[v, 16];
        C1_ = new decimal[v, 16];
        TOT_pie1 = new decimal[v];
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constrSHALER"].ConnectionString))
        {
             int day;
             //for (int j = 0; j <= month-1; j++)
             //   {
             year = ano_;
             foreach (int j in ddl_mes_int)
             {
                 //j = j - 1;

                day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, j);
                if (month < 10)
                {
                    month_s = "0" + j;
                }
                else
                {
                    month_s = j.ToString();
                }
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Bonificadas_ruta", sqlcon))
                {
                    //string b = pt[n_].ToString();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechao", (year + month_s + "01").ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", (year + month_s + day).ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", "PT-001.");
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    { 
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            da.Fill(dt);

                            // Declare an object variable.
                            object sumObject;
                            sumObject = dt.Compute("Sum(costo)", "");

                            TOT_pie1[j - 1] = Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);                             
                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-01")
                                {
                                    Name[0] = "R1";
                                    Ruta[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto      
                                    RutaP[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-02")
                                {
                                    Name[1] = "R2";
                                    Ruta[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto     
                                    RutaP[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-03")
                                {
                                    Name[2] = "R3";
                                    Ruta[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto   
                                    RutaP[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-04")
                                {
                                    Name[3] = "R4";
                                    Ruta[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto     
                                    RutaP[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-05")
                                {
                                    Name[4] = "R5";
                                    Ruta[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto  
                                    RutaP[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-06")
                                {
                                    Name[5] = "R6";
                                    Ruta[5] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[5] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto  
                                    RutaP[5] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-07")
                                {
                                    Name[6] = "R7";
                                    Ruta[6] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[6] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto    
                                    RutaP[6] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-08")
                                {
                                    Name[7] = "R8";
                                    Ruta[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto 
                                    RutaP[7] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-09")
                                {
                                    Name[8] = "R9";
                                    Ruta[8] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[8] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto   
                                    RutaP[8] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-10")
                                {
                                    Name[9] = "R10";
                                    Ruta[9] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[9] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto   
                                    RutaP[9] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-11")
                                {
                                    Name[10] = "R11";
                                    Ruta[10] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[10] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto      
                                    RutaP[10] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-CLIENTE")
                                {
                                    Name[11] = "CLIENTE";
                                    Ruta[11] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[11] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto   
                                    RutaP[11] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-INST")
                                {
                                    Name[12] = "INST.";
                                    Ruta[12] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[12] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto    
                                    RutaP[12] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-PLANTA")
                                {
                                    Name[13] = "PLANTA";
                                    Ruta[13] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[13] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto      
                                    RutaP[13] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-PREV-01")
                                {
                                    Name[14] = "PREV. 1";
                                    Ruta[14] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[14] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto     
                                    RutaP[14] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }
                                if (row["WAREHOUSE_ID"].ToString() == "VEN-PREV-02")
                                {
                                    Name[15] = "PREV. 2";
                                    Ruta[15] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CANT"]);  //Cantidad
                                    Ruta_[15] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]); //Monto    
                                    RutaP[15] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["COSTO"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(sumObject);
                                }

                            }
                    }
                }

                    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 2)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 3)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 4)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 5)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 6)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 7)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 8)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 9)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 10)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 11)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 12)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 13)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 14)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }
                        if (i == 15)
                        {
                            C1[j - 1, i] = Ruta[i];  //Cantidad
                            C1_[j - 1, i] = Ruta_[i]; //Monto
                        }

                        //En el load inicial , mandamos el último mes consultado al jquery.
                        if (j == (month - 1))
                        {

                        kbItems.Add(new KBInfo1_III_B()
                        {
                            ruta = Name[i],
                            a3 = RutaP[i],
                            Cant = Ruta[i],
                            Monto = Ruta_[i]

                        });

                        }
                    }

        }       

            }


        return kbItems;
    }




   [WebMethod]
    public static List<CharItem1> Pie1_WM(string name)
    {
        int month = Convert.ToInt16(name) - 1;
        List<CharItem1> ListPie = new List<CharItem1>();
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R1", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 0], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 0], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 0] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R2", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 1], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 1], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 1] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R3", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 2], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 2], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 2] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R4", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 3], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 3], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 3] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R5", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 4], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 4], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 4] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R6", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 5], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 5], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 5] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R7", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 6], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 6], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 6] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R8", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 7], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 7], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 7] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R9", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 8], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 8], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 8] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R10", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 9], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 9], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 9] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "R11", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 10], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 10], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 10] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "CLIENTE", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 11], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 11], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 11] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "INST.", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 12], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 12], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 12] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "PLANTA", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 13], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 13], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 13] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "PREV. 1", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 14], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 14], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 14] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        ListPie.Add(new CharItem1() { ruta = "PREV. 2", Cant = DataHelper3.C1[(month), 15], Monto = DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 15], a3 = (DataHelper3.C1_[(month), 15] / DataHelper3.TOT_pie1[(month)]) });
        return ListPie;
    }
```

Comprendo que lo mejor sería volver a consultar al servidor, pero se me hizo algo difícil consultarlo y enviar la respuesta al clientside con ayuda del webmethod ya que éste no me permitía usar el lenguaje de conexion SQL y comandos. Seguramente es aquí el problema. O tal vez usar variables de tipo Session.

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que no recomendaria el camino que estas tomando, el static puede tener problemas de acceso concurente y dar dolores de cabeza

Lo que recomendaria es que esas variables separadas las definas en alguna entidad, o sea definas una clase con una estructura mas significativa que simples variables sueltas

Entonces por medio de la opciones de cache mantengas los datos

[Tutorial: Almacenar en caché datos de la aplicación en ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff477235.aspx)

si el webmethod es static puedes usar el [HttpContext.Current.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx) para accederlo

Basicamente que el metodo GetER1_B() generaria los datos y ademas de devolverlos los pondria en cache, cuando quieras acceder a estos validas si estan en cache, si lo estan los tomas de alli, sino invocas al metodo para ir nuevamente contra la db y recuperar datos actualziados porque la cache expiro